# Var in var = var in var + 1

Tags: lua, nested, var, hidden

I am still new to Lua and have one question about var in var.

How do I calculate this:?

```
A=1
X=A
X=X+1
```

As you can see:
This calculation would result in

```
A=A+1
```

But this does not work for me.
I guess I have to format the cars in some way.

I want to do this because I want to be able to change a var in another var when necessary.

Comment: In Lua you can't pass a numeric value by reference.  But you can pass a table with this value inside.  Global variables are already in a table: `A=1; varname="A"; _G[varname]=_G[varname]+1`

Comment: In most (all?) programming languages,`X=A; X=X+1` is never equivalent to `A=A+1`.

Answer (score 2):

The = operator does two things:

- Evaluate the right-hand side
- Assign the result to the variable on the left-hand side

To illustrate, consider this example:

```
A = 1            -- A is now 1
X = A + A + A    -- X is now 3, and A hasn't changed
X = X + 1        -- X is now 4, and A hasn't changed
```

Now lets look at your original code, and write out the meaning in plain language.

```
A=1         -- Create a variable 'A' and assign it the value of one
X=A         -- Create the variable 'X' and assign it the current value of 'A'
X=X+1       -- Change 'X' by assigning it the current value of 'X' plus one
```

Notice how these comments read like "instructions" to a computer, rather than math equations.  Lua (and programming in general) should be interpreted as a set of instructions executed from top to bottom.

However, as Egor Skriptunoff alludes to in earlier comments, tables behave differently.  See [Programming in Lua - Chapter 2.5](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) for a more detailed explanation of how tables are different.